# Remove Ads On Other Views

Tags: xcode, swift, view, ads

I am trying to make an in-app-purchase to remove the ads across all views. This func removes the ad on this view but how could I make it remove it for al views.

```
func removeAds() {
    Ad1.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all the view controllers object in an array:

> NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: navigationController.viewControllers];

Then traverse through the array using fast enumeration or for loop to get viewcontroller object and remove adds.

Comment: How would you write this for swift?

Comment: @DB3, Sorry I am new to Swift.